Grafana elasticsearch lucene query to limit columns
In grafana I'm using elasticsearch data source with the query type of Logs. All the colums are displayed but I just want to see 2 of 3 of them , source_timestamp , access_Type and active_event_count. I want to know if I can use Lucene.
Note I know I can use the transform >> Organize fields by name and turn off each column. But there are a ton columns in this dataset and there is no negate features (hid all but only display a few) and the columns can grow later on which would affect my visuals if I'm only toggling them off to filter

I've tried putting these into the Lucene Query field but does not display anything :

_fields: [@source_timestamp,access_type, active_events_count]
_fields: ["@source_timestamp","access_type", "active_events_count"]


Visually fixes the problem:
This visually solves the problem if I go to override >> Fields with name matching Regex and add in ^(?!@source_timestamp$|access_type$|component_bitrate$).+$  + Hide in Table.
I'm not marking it as the answer because it doesn't limit the columns via query. But adding it as an answer because it does work well , visually
